# Angular: two slickgrids, same page

Tags: angularjs, slickgrid

I'm new to Angular, so, please, don't be too harsh on me. I'm trying to edit this example: https://github.com/fortesl/angular-slickgrid-example to work with two grids.

Here's the working plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/RyAwvqZ9sr3b9YFvmK2X 
The problem is that when you double click on any row on the first grid it gets deleted. However, it doesn't work for the second grid.

The easiest way to approach this problem is to create the second deleteTask method in the controller:

```
self.deleteTask2 = function(row) {
  self.data2.splice(row.row, 1);
}
```

And change the attribute for the second grid to use this function.

However, this approach doesn't seem right. What if there will be a third/forth and so on grid? Is there a way in angular to make the deleteTask a part of the directive, not scope?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: FYI, the [6pac repo](https://github.com/6pac/SlickGrid) has an example of dynamically created multiple grids

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just modify the `deleteTask` function to take the data array you want to delete from.

[Working, modified version of the Plunker code](http://plnkr.co/edit/fXFkY83Ju0kz7CReFAW4?p=preview)

Controller:

```
self.deleteTask = function(data, row) {
    data.splice(row.row, 1);
}
```

View:

```
<div my-grid style="width:600px;height:200px;" grid-columns="gridCtrl.columns"
     grid-options="gridCtrl.options" grid-data="gridCtrl.data"
     edit-row="gridCtrl.deleteTask(gridCtrl.data, row)" class="container myGrid">
</div>
```

Comment: Yeah this is embarrassing. Thanks for the answer! But we bind data with grid-data="gridCtrl.data". Is there a way to use this fact in the function?

Comment: Do you mean if `edit-row` implicitly passes the `grid-data` bindings to the provided function? As far as I can tell, that doesn't happen; it purely calls the function, with the parameters provided.

Comment: I, probably, need more time with this to fully realize it! Thanks again for your answers!

Comment: I'm still reading the code on Github, so I may see something that changes my answer regarding that. For now, though, this works, and should play nicely with `ngRepeat` (just remember not to use IDs if you do that).

Comment: OK, the problem that I have with it is, for example, if I add new instances dynamically and pass them data. Do I need an array of data linked to each instance? I understand that it is the angular way to separate the data, so it has to be stored in $scope, is that correct? Or is there a way in directive itself to find the data it is linked to (if data is linked through the `grid-data` attribute why double mention it in the function parameter)?

Comment: An array of each instance would be the way I'd do it, yes. That way, you can just iterate over it with ngRepeat, and the edit-row attribute will be hooked up to the correct data set automatically. It's your choice if you want to put it in $scope or leave it as a property of the controller like it is already. Here is a working example of that. As I said, I'm still looking through the source on Github to see if there's a way to get the data from the scope/context.

Comment: Woops, accidentally deleted the link to the `ngRepeat` example. [Here it is](http://plnkr.co/edit/LSUni6WYqidYywTUBGgF?p=preview).

Comment: Thank you very much for the detailed answer!